# Connection closed error after some idle time

Tags: sql-server, azure, spring-boot, sql-server-2012, multi-tenant

I have a multi-tenant application where one DB per tenant with one Master DB is configured. I load all the data sources in applications something like this :

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {

    if(LOGGER.isInfoEnabled())
        LOGGER.info("Loading datasources ...");

    DataSource ds = null;
    JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();

    // load MASTER datasource
    ds = dataSourceLookup.getDataSource(properties.getJndiName());

    // load other TENANTs DB details
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    List<GroupConfig> groupConfigs = jdbcTemplate.query(
            "select * from master.tblTenant where IsActive=1 and ConfigCode in ('DB_URL','DATASOURCE_CLASS','USER_NAME','DB_PASSWORD') order by 2",
            new ResultSetExtractor<List<GroupConfig>>() {

                public List<GroupConfig> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                    List<GroupConfig> list = new ArrayList<GroupConfig>();

                    while (rs.next()) {
                        GroupConfig groupConfig = new GroupConfig();

                        groupConfig.setGroupConfigId(rs.getLong(1));
                        groupConfig.setGroupCode(rs.getString(2));
                        groupConfig.setConfigCode(rs.getString(3));
                        groupConfig.setConfigValue(rs.getString(4));
                        groupConfig.setIsActive(rs.getBoolean(5));
                        list.add(groupConfig);
                    }

                    return list;
                }

            });

    int propCount = 1;
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> groups = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
    Map<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (GroupConfig config : groupConfigs) {
        temp.put(config.getConfigCode(), config.getConfigValue());
        if (propCount % 4 == 0) {
            groups.put(config.getGroupCode(), temp);
            temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
        }

        propCount++;
    }

    // Create TENANT dataSource
    Map<Object, Object> resolvedDataSources = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

    for (String tenantId : groups.keySet()) {

        Map<String, String> groupKV = groups.get(tenantId);
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = new DataSourceBuilder(this.getClass().getClassLoader());

        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(groupKV.get("DATASOURCE_CLASS")).url(groupKV.get("DB_URL"))
                .username(groupKV.get("USER_NAME")).password(groupKV.get("DB_PASSWORD"));

        //System.out.println(dataSourceBuilder.findType()); //class org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource

        if (properties.getType() != null) {
            dataSourceBuilder.type(properties.getType());
        }

        if(LOGGER.isInfoEnabled())
            LOGGER.info("Building datasource : "+tenantId);
        resolvedDataSources.put(tenantId, dataSourceBuilder.build());

    }


    resolvedDataSources.put("MASTER", ds);


    MultitenantDataSource dataSource = new MultitenantDataSource();
    dataSource.setTargetDataSources(resolvedDataSources);
    dataSource.setDataSourceLookup(dataSourceLookup);       
    dataSource.afterPropertiesSet();

    if(LOGGER.isInfoEnabled())
        LOGGER.info("Datasources initialization finished !");

    return dataSource;
}
```

In controller I set respective data source as (similarly for TENANT datasources) :

```
TenantContext.setCurrentTenant("MASTER");
```

**Issue :** On server startup every thing works fine (both MASTER DB and TENANT specific queries), but once the server is idle for some time (few Hours) tenant specific calls starts failing (while MASTER DB connections still works fine) with error :

> Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.

Please help me to get rid off this exception. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Slight detour. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal For the issue at hand it seems that you need to check the connection and open it first.

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem and solutions as well:

**Why tenant connections was getting closed?** Because Auto configurations(@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")) of spring-boot was not getting applied on the tenant DataSources which I was creating in code.

**Resolution-** I added new method to set the tomcat connection pool properties:

```
private DataSource buildDataSource(String driverClass, String url, String user, String pass){

    PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
    p.setUrl(url);
    p.setDriverClassName(driverClass);
    p.setUsername(user);
    p.setPassword(pass);
    p.setJmxEnabled(true);
    p.setTestWhileIdle(false);
    p.setTestOnBorrow(true); 
    p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
    p.setTestOnReturn(false);
    p.setValidationInterval(30000);
    p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
    p.setMaxActive(100);
    p.setInitialSize(10);
    p.setMaxWait(10000);
    p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
    p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
    p.setMinIdle(10);
    p.setLogAbandoned(true);
    p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
    DataSource datasource = new DataSource();
    datasource.setPoolProperties(p);

    return  datasource;
}
```

This solved my problem. But I'm curious to know if there is a way to apply AutoConfigurations while creating the objects in spring-boot.